# iOS 13: Announce messages with Siri

Tags: ios, ios13, siri, usernotifications

I want to implement the "announce messages with Siri" feature for my own app. I haven't seen any app that is able to do it except for Messages from Apple. So I don't know if its already available. Apple announced it without any limitations explicit and mentioned that everyone will be able to adopt it.

How do I get Siri announcements for incoming notifications working?

I requested the permissions and can’t find anything else in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unauthorizationoptions/3240649-announcement).
It also won’t show up in the settings app.

[image]

For reference Apples WWDC 2019 Keynote (56:00 - 56:40):

https://youtu.be/psL_5RIBqnY?t=3360

Comment: That is a great question! I saw this option (announcement) in the UNAuthorizationOptions. After searching online, I also couldn't find any info about it.
I have reached out to Apple to ask about this option and I will let you know if I get a relevant answer.

Comment: @Sam the option you're referring to is for Airpods: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unauthorizationoptions/3240649-announcement. I don't think we can get the same behavior as iMessage has where Siri can always read out messages

Comment: @donnywals, so as far as I understand, there is an option to have Siri read out notifications when wearing AirPods? I have granted permission, enabled Siri but couldn't get this to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: I added the keynote reference. Apple is explicit mentioning third party apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As per Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/insendmessageintent):

> To have messages automatically heard by a user wearing AirPods, you must implement both [`INSearchForMessagesIntent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/insearchformessagesintent) and [`INSendMessageIntent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/insendmessageintent). Add [`announcement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unauthorizationoptions/3240649-announcement) to the options when calling [`requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649527-requestauthorization). Finally, add [`allowAnnouncement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcategoryoptions/3240647-allowannouncement) to the category option and [`INSearchForMessagesIntent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/insearchformessagesintent) to the category intent identifier.

In summary, adding the [`announcement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unauthorizationoptions/3240649-announcement) option won't magically start reading your push notifications via AirPods. The functionality only works alongside Siri's support for messaging apps. I would advise against adding the Siri functionality to a non-messaging app as you are likely to be rejected.